# Why do we have to mention Solidity version?

Tags: solidity, web3js

While writing code in solidity, why do we have to mention the compiler version?

Answer (score 2):

It's mostly a hint for the compiler and for user-friendliness; it tells the compiler that the code is meant to work on certain versions of Solidity and that it may not work on other versions. Furthermore, it tells the compiler to raise warnings/errors if the compiler uses a version which is incompatible with the version defined in the code.

If it was allowed to leave it out it wouldn't cause direct issues with code - only indirect problems when some code is run on wrong versions of Solidity. There would be no way for the user to know that the code will not work (or worse, will work incorrectly).

You can find some more info for example here: https://www.bitdegree.org/learn/solidity-version-pragma/